# Android studio 2.2 NDK configruation error

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

I have download ndk and start to make demo for "Hello World"
Make project with ref [Android studio NDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#new-project)

Download Cmake and put in sdk folder.
No change in code during gradle sync there is error like:

```
External Native Build Issues

Error while executing 'D:\android\Sdk\cmake\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {-HD:\Data\Demo\TestNDK\app -BD:\Data\Demo\TestNDK\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=D:\android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\Data\Demo\TestNDK\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\android\Sdk\cmake\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=22 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-frtti -fexceptions}

CMake Error: Could not create named generator Android Gradle - Ninja

Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
```

Getting above error in default NDK Setting

Comment: You have not isntalled ninje?

Comment: From where i need to install?
I have install LLBG,NDK from Tools

Comment: I won't explain how to install Ninja. There are tutorials and their website and Google. Show some effort instead of just copying your errors to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

> Download Cmake and put in sdk folder.

You need to get cmake via the SDK manager to use it with Android Studio.