# CMake isn't available from Android Studio SDK Tools

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

I want to build project using native code and to do this I need CMake but it isn't available from Android Studio SDK Tools.. When I install it manually it isn't work out.. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39858398/6296729) I have to install CMake from SDK Tools, not manually, but CMake isn't in SKD Tools:
[image: CMake isnt available]
I use Android Studio 2.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reinstalling Android Studio helped.**